# How to import all the environment variables in tox

Tags: python, virtualenv, setenv, tox

I'm using following in setenv to import the environment variable from where I run, but is there a way to import all the variables so that I don't really need to import one by one.

e.g:
{env:TEMPEST_CONFIG:} and {env:TEMPEST_CONFIG_DIR:} used to import these 2 variables.

```
[testenv:nosetests]
setenv =
    TEMPEST_CONFIG={env:TEMPEST_CONFIG:}
    TEMPEST_CONFIG_DIR={env:TEMPEST_CONFIG_DIR:}
deps = {[testenv]deps}
commands =
    find . -type f -name "*.pyc" -delete
    bash {toxinidir}/tools/setup.sh
    nosetests --with-xunit {posargs}
```

Answer (score 59):

You can use [passenv](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-passenv=SPACE-SEPARATED-GLOBNAMES). If you pass the catch all wildcard `*` you have access to all environment variables from the parent environment:

> passenv=SPACE-SEPARATED-GLOBNAMES
>
> *New in version 2.0.*
>
> A list of wildcard environment variable names which shall  be copied
>   from the tox invocation environment to the test  environment when
>   executing test commands. If a specified  environment variable doesn’t
>   exist in the tox invocation  environment it is ignored. You can use *
>   and ? to match  multiple environment variables with one name.

minimal `tox.ini` to reproduce (no project necessary):

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
passenv = *
skip_install = True
commands = python -c "print('computer says {env:MY_FANCY_ENV_VAR:}!')"
```

invocation in linux/unix shell:

```
MY_FANCY_ENV_VAR=no tox -qq
```

invocation on Windows cmd.exe:

```
set MY_FANCY_ENV_VAR=no & tox -qq
```

output:

```
computer says no!
```