# Python not seeing environment variables on GitHub Actions

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, tox

I have some pytest tests that connect to a test Postgres DB. These work well locally. However, on GitHub actions, there's no Postgres DB, so I have to disable the entire module that has these tests.

According to [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables), `CI Always set to true.` So all I have to do is check for the CI env-var, and disable the tests module if it's present and set:

```py
if os.getenv('CI'):
    pytest.skip("No PostgreSQL on GH Actions CI/CD", allow_module_level=True)
```

Doesn't work.

I have tried setting it manually, setting other env-vars manually via `env:`, but none of them are visible to Python. Disabling the module locally by negating the above test `not os.getenv('CI')` works as expected.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. I'm using [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run the tests among other things. Turns out tox doesn't copy the parent env unless it's told to via the `passenv` directive. Here's the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252679/433717) that cleared it up.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't shown us any any code, but if I set up a repository with the following `.github/workflows/environment.yml`:

```
---
name: "Environment test"
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  show_environment:
    name: "Show environment variables"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Show environmetn variables"
        run: |
          env

  python_test:
    name: "Reproduce behavior from https://stackoverflow.com/q/65382013/147356"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Checkout repository"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: "Set up python"
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: "Run python script"
        run: |
          python actiontest.py
```

And include this `actiontest.py` in the repository:

```
import os

if os.getenv('CI'):
    print('Looks like GitHub!')
else:
    print('Maybe running locally?')
```

It all seems to work as documented. The [show environment](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-65382013/runs/1585200314?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:26) shows that the `CI` variable is defined as expected, and the [actiontest.py script](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-65382013/runs/1585200340?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:7) successfully detects that variable.

If you are seeing different behavior, please include a complete reproducible example in your question and we would be happy to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: @larsks thanks. Your answer gave me an idea that led to me finding the solution below.